# React TypeScript default Type for Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm facing some issues to type this component:

```
type Props = {
  collectionName: string;
};

export const CollectionName = ({ title, ...rest }: Props) => {
  return !collectionName || collectionName === 'null' ? (
    <TitlePlaceHolder {...rest} />
  ) : rest.heading ? (
    <Heading>{title}</Heading>
  ) : (
    <Text fontSize="xs" color="textlight.tertiary" {...rest}>
      {title}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

What i need to put on rest to make it compatible with everything?

Comment: { title, ...rest }: Props won't work because your Props type has no title property.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that you have your props defined in your type, also you can use ...rest when you know what props it will have

```
type Props = {
  collectionName: string;
  title: string;
  heading?: boolean;
};

export const CollectionName = ({ collectionName, title, heading }: Props) => {
  if (!collectionName) return <TitlePlaceHolder />;
  else if (heading) return <Heading>{title}</Heading>;

  return (
    <Text fontSize='xs' color='textlight.tertiary'>
      {title}
    </Text>
  );
};
```